# retaining drop down value after submit in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a drop down pull from an oracle database. when I select a drop down value and click a show details button , the details show but the drop down defaults back to the first one in the list. I need it to stay on the selected value.

I am doing this in PHP

I have tried this but it cannot recognize the

```
<form name= "fund" method="post" >
 <label id= "fund" for="fund">Fund:</label>
 <Select  name="fund" id="fund">
<option value="--Select A Fund--">--Select a Fund--</option>
 <?php 


 $sql = 'SELECT Account_name ||\' - \'|| Fund_id as FUND, FUND_ID FROM FUND_ACCOUNTS';


 

     $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql); 
     $success = oci_execute($stid); 
     while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC))  
     {  
         $selected = (!empty($_POST['fund']) &&  $_POST['fund'] == $row['FUND']) ? 'selected' : ''; 
     echo '<option value="' . $row['FUND'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $row['FUND'] . '</option>';
     } 
     
    
    ?> 
    
    </select> 
    
     <input type="submit" name="fund"
                    value="Show Current Fund Investors"/> 
        </form> 
    
    
    <BR>
    
    <?php
     echo 1 . $row['FUND']; 
     echo 1 . $_POST['fund']; 
    
    
    ?>
```

But $selected is never populated. Not sure where to go from here, and I am not a web developer. Any ideas where I am going wrong ?

the output of the final echos is 11Show Current Fund Investors

Comment: What does error reporting reveal?

Comment: there are no errors, everything else on the page is working as intended except as soon as I change the dropdown value and click show details, the drop down defaults back to the original value,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely this line just needs to do this:

```
$selected = (!empty($_POST['fund']) &&  $_POST['fund'] == $row['FUND'])) ? 'selected' : '';
```

What you have is matching the default option with  `|| ($row['FUND'] == '--Select A Fund--')` and probably also adding `selected` to the one you actually do select from the drop down. View the page source in the browser, there might be two options with the `selected` attribute.

By default, if nothing is selected, it will just show the first item in the dropdown which is `--Select A Fund--` anyway.

Also you probably should have a space before the `$selected` variable and after the quote:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['FUND'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $row['FUND'] . '</option>';
```

Should come out to:

```
<option value="whatever" selected>Whatever</option>
```

---

**Edit**

Based on your edit, you need to remove the name attribute from the submit button, or rename it. It’s conflicting with your `select` name.

```
<input type="submit" value="Show Current Fund Investors"/>
```

**A tip:**

You should encapsulate your fetching of that list in a function (at the very least) and include it in the page at the top:

**/functions/fetchFundAccounts.php**

```
<?php
function fetchFundAccounts($conn)
{
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT Account_name ||\' - \'|| Fund_id as FUND, FUND_ID FROM FUND_ACCOUNTS'); 

     $success = oci_execute($stid);
     $results = [];
     while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) {  
         $results[] = $row;
     }
     return $results;
}
```

To use:

```
<?php include(__DIR__.'/functions/fetchFundAccounts.php') ?>

<form name= "fund" method="post" >
    <label id= "fund" for="fund">Fund:</label>
    <select  name="fund" id="fund">
        <option value="--Select A Fund--">--Select a Fund--</option>
        <?php foreach(fetchFundAccounts($conn) as $row): ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $row['FUND'] ?>" <?php echo (!empty($_POST['fund']) &&  $_POST['fund'] == $row['FUND']) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $row['FUND'] ?></option>

        <?php endforeach ?> 
    
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Show Current Fund Investors"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: I tried that but it seems like my $row['fund'] and $_POST['fund'] are not being set

Comment: @lazyleprechaun Also, your last line `echo 1 . $row['FUND']; ` is only going to show the last iterated value from the fetched db array, so that is not giving you an accurate picture of any matching of selection. If your `$_POST['fund']` is empty there after submission, then you have something up with that.

Comment: @lazyleprechaun I have edited to include one "tip" if you are interested in cleaning up your code and also in reusability.